# Iterating string with strchr in C

Tags: c, loops, strchr

If I have a string like `char str [] = "hello;people;how;are;you"` 
and use `strchr(str,";")` how can I take the N-th token of the string?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you are storing the strchr in a char * ch

Then ch-str+1 will return you the position of the character that you looked for in strchr

Using a predefined substring function or defining a function of your own you can create a while loop like this :

```
i=0;
while(ch != NULL)
{
    printf("Your subsrting is : %s", substring_function(i,(ch-str+1)));
    i = ch-str+1;
    ch=strchr(ch+1,';');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will use `strchr` , which has as argument the token, not the position i.

Comment: You do not change `ch` in the loop, so it is an endless loop.

Comment: @polegar this should work strchr is taking two arguments the pointer and  the character you are looking for in the string

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution with `strtok` and I'd like to convert it using `strchr`. Tokenizer is static variable which contains the character for tokenizing.  Any ideas?

```
static const char *a(const char *string,int tkn) {
    char *tokenized=strdup(string);
    char *token;
    token=strtok(tokenized, tokenizer);
    int i=0;
    while(token != NULL) {
      if (i == (tkn-1)) {
        break;
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, tokenizer);
      i++;
   }
   return token;
}
```

Comment: This approach is a memory leak as the allocated `tokenized` is not certainly recoverable for a later `free()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can add a free after all. Beyond that?

Comment: "I can add a free after all" --> It is not that simple as code returns a pointer into allocated memory, but has lost the beginning of it.  Suggest posting an answer that uses your "add a free" idea.

Comment: Delete strdup, use string directly in strtok with casting to char *.

Comment: Using `strtok(string)` on a `const char *` is undefined behavior.  Try coding it and see if your well enabled compiler warns.